# Suspicious JVM Time Behavior

Tags: java, time, jvm

I have totally strange problem on one of my machines. I've written a program which is monitoring events from our servers and displays them on a monitoring pc. However, each event status message also contains a TIMESTAMP which is being retrieved by the following calls:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

with
    public static final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

I'm expecting this call to return the local time, which is and was working great until today. But now my program shows me the local time +3 hours on every incoming event. A restart of the jar file does not help at all and the System Time is also set up correctly. This program is running on a machine which is synchronizing its time with an central corporate clock.

Can anyone explain me the mentioned behavior and/or state a possible solution which is not "restart the machine and try again" :-) ?

Cliffs:
- Retrival of Time is working on my- or any other machine when I start the Program
- The target Machine is running 24/7 and is only a monitoring machine, so no one is changing any options there
- It worked fine until today.
- All Time/Timezone settings on the Hostsystem (Windows XP) are correct. (checked via CMD -> "date" and also over the System Preferences)

I appreciate any kind of answer to this issue. Thank you for your time!

---

the Question is answered since the 25 already. I've implemented a explicit call of Timezone.setDefault() to make sure that the proper timezone is being shown the whole time. I'll close this Question now.

Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: Hi, yes, all Date and Time options on the system side are correct

Comment: I meant the timezone of your Calendar and SimpleDateFormat objects.

Comment: See my comment to Answer 1 below. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
cal.getTime()
```

Returns a `Date` object. A `Date` object is simply a wrapper for the UTC time as a `long`. In the code you showed us, it is just as correct to do `sdf.format(new Date());`

What is the format `DATE_FORMAT_NOW`? I assume you specify this yourself. Do you specify the timezone in this format?

**EDIT** As you mentioned in your comment, DATE_FORMAT_NOW does not specify a timezone. You should do both `Timezone.getDefault()` and `sdf.getTimezone()` to see if the value has changed to your locale + 3 hours.

**EDIT2** I found [this forum post](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t144537-default-timezone-changes-out-of-nowhere.html) about the time sporadically changing. In this case it was caused by an Oracle driver calling `Timezone.setDefault(...)` in the middle of a method, then setting it back afterwards.

Comment: Hi, it is      public static final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";   . Well the above mentioned code worked fine until today. When I start the program on my- or any other machine, it still works correct. The machine which is running the program, is running 24/7.

Comment: What does `sdf.getTimeZone()` return?

Comment: Hi, it shows a wrong timezone , Asia/Karachi. The gettime command is also still returning the wrong time. But the System Time is set up correctly to the local time (Timezone: GMT+2). How can the JVM change its timezone automatically and more important is the question: HOW can I change it back during its runtime?

Comment: Timezone.getDefault() returns the same value as sdf.getTimezone(), both are the system time +3h :-(. Can I change the TIMEZONE during the runtime of the jvm somehow ? e.g. "java -xyz <new timezone>" ?

Comment: This means that something is setting the default timezone. It is possible that there is a library that does this, or even some of your own code. See my answer for an example.

Comment: Though it seems strange, it's possible that something somewhere called `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Karachi"))`. To change it back, to say, UTC, just call `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))`

Comment: There is a property to specify the timezone e.g. `-Duser.timezone=UTC` but this will be overridden by any call to `Timezone.setDefault(...)`.

Comment: Hi, i've solved the problem now in the source code itself, by forcing the proper timezone with the setDefault Command. Thank you guys for your time and answers :-)